# When do p-values and likelihoods correlate?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $_1,\ldots,_$ be independent and identically distributed from a distribution $\mathbb{ℙ}_$ with unknown parameter $\in Θ$.

For every $\hat\theta ∈Θ$, we can consider the pointwise hypothesis $:=\hat\theta$ , perform a two-sided statistical test to calculate the p-value function $(̂ )$, and the likelihood of the data given that hypothesis $(̂)$.

If $\mathbb{P}_$ is a Bernoulli distribution, then the following two are equivalent for all $\theta_1,\theta_2 \in \Theta$:

1. $p(\theta_1)>p(\theta_2)$
2. $f(\theta_1)>f(\theta_2).$

That is, if one hypothesis results in a higher p-value than another under a two-tailed statistical test, then it also makes the data more likely.

Other distributions share this feature (e.g., the Normal distribution with a known variance.) My question is: under what general conditions will a distribution share this feature?

Comment: It would probably be better to ask this on Cross Validated.

Comment: Daily vote limit reached, but I agree with @Joe.